Where to put "to me"?
Where do we put "to me or him or her"?

Explain the rules to me

Explain to us why you really wanted to kill her


When it comes to the verb "explain" if the object is short we put "to me" at the end whereas once it is long we put it right after "explain".
What about recommed, suggest or something similar. Is there a rule too?

I recommend to him she read more

I recommend she read more to him

I suggest to him she do it

I suggest she do it to him


To me they are all fine yet 4 and 6 sound a little ambiquous. Like do I want her to read more to him or just I want her to read more and I inform him about that? So, is there a rule like the one with explain?

I wouldn't call (4) and (6) ambiguous, I would say they definitely have a different meaning.

@KateBunting thank you. What would you say about these two? "Several friends have recommended this restaurant to me vs recommended to me this restaurant" both good?

The first is idiomatic, the second would make you sound like a non-native speaker.

@KateBunting so, second reveals my true identity haha

Yeah, 2 is oveer the top.

There's nearly always more than one way to phrase something.
Both "explain the rules to me" and "explain to me the rules" are correct, but placing the indirect object ("to me") before the direct object ("the rules") tends to sounds more formal.
Of course, "explain" requires the indirect object to have a preposition - it is wrong to say "explain me...". In contexts where that isn't the case, the reverse may be true. For example "tell James your story" sounds a fraction more informal than "tell your story to James".
The overarching principle of any speech is that it is clear and understandable. So, when thinking about phrasing you would want the placement of any objects to aid comprehension and avoid ambiguity. Your example of "I recommend she read more to him" as written suggests that 'she' has partially read something to 'him' but there is more to read. Changing that around to "I recommend she read to him more" alters the meaning completely and would be understood as more often.
So, there isn't a single answer to your question that fixes all of your examples in the same way. You'll have to consider each on its merits.
